# Is there a good equivalent to Mint.com for users outside the USA?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'd love to use Mint.com but it's not available in the UK. Any idea when it might be available in the UK, or are there any recommended UK equivalents?

Comment: Thanks. It's not really money/finance related advice I'm looking for though, more the multiple account synchronisation, management and tracking services.

Comment: Ditto for a Canadian equivalent which would also be nice.

Comment: I vote to change the title to something more generic; "...for users not in the US"

Comment: I say keep it UK as each country has different services. If you make it "non US" then it would have to be a CW.

Comment: I'd prefer it to be more generic, but that it SHOULD include the UK. Surely there must be Mint.com clones that have worldwide coverage?

Answer (score 7):

[Money Dashboard](http://www.moneydashboard.com/) finally went public beta recently

> **Are you still searching around in different places for your financial
>   information?**
>
> Money Dashboard can help you save time
>   and effort by gathering all of your
>   online banking accounts together in
>   one place so you can easily review all
>   of your recent transactions from
>   different sources on a single site.
>
> **Ever wondered where all your money goes?**
>
> Now it's as easy as pie to find out
>   where all your hard earned cash has
>   gone every month. Money Dashboard tags
>   your transactions so you can see
>   exactly how much you’re spending.
>
> Armed with that information you can
>   identify where savings can be made and
>   set a budget you can actually achieve.
>
> **It feels good to know how much money you have to play with**
>
> Your Money Dashboard makes it much
>   easier to budget because it gives you
>   a clear view of your spending pattern
>   and financial situation at any point
>   in time.
>
> That means that when you do splash
>   your hard earned cash, you know you
>   can actually afford to.
>
> **Want your finances to move up a gear?**
>
> If you have big plans for the future,
>   we’re here to help you achieve them.
>
> You can make the most of our top tips
>   on saving money and growing your
>   personal wealth too, through our
>   blogs, tweets and “Ways to Save”
>   pages.
>
> So financial planning for a prosperous
>   future has never been more
>   straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** Xero Personal [has been discontinued as of November 2014](https://www.xero.com/blog/2013/08/winding-down-xero-personal-in-november-2014/).

[Xero Personal](https://www.xero.com/personal/) may do what you want.

> **Get to know your money better**
>
> Xero is the easiest way to keep track of your personal spending habits and savings goals.
>
> **Get your complete financial position in an instant**
>
> Xero lets you organise all your bank accounts in one place and automatically tracks your spending for you.
>
> **Automatically keeps you on top of things**
>
> Xero automatically categorises your spending and saving, so you can tell whether your money is being used for essentials or you're splashing out on other things. Interactive graphs make it immediately obvious what's happening
>
> **Designed to work with your lifestyle**
>
> If it’s been a tough month, Xero will show you what you need to do to get back on track. Xero even works on your schedule, based on when and how often you get paid.
>
> **Stay in the loop & stay secure**
>
> Invite people you trust, such as your spouse or financial advisor, to access Xero for free. They can help you plan ahead and make the most of your money. Xero protects your financial data with 128-bit SSL encryption, the same as online banking, so you can rest assured your data is well protected.

I havn't used their 'personal' offering myself but I do use their business version daily and love it, I don't know how I'd keep up with things without it.

Edit: One drawback is that it Xero Personal doesn't offer automatic import (that I could find). You will still need to export your accounts from your banks website.

Comment: It is commercial and I doesn't provide integration with any UK bank, only manual upload of statements.

Comment: Xero Personal is being discontinued as of November 2014: http://www.xero.com/blog/2013/08/winding-down-xero-personal-in-november-2014/

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [Buxfer](http://www.buxfer.com), since it allows you to do both automatic and by hand transactions (since im in mexico and my bank is not supported by mint I needed hand made transactions).

Its simple and easy but have a lot of info and reports, i like it :)

Answer (score 1):

[www.anzmoneymanager.com](http://www.anzmoneymanager.com)

is an australian site that supports international bank accounts and may suit your needs.

Slick interface and reports/categories/budgets and regular synch.

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone here used [lovemoney.com](https://www.lovemoney.com/onlinebanking/)? Our account aggregation service went live last November. lovemoney.com provides users with the opportunity to manage all of their money in one place. The application is particularly useful for monitoring overspending and for setting savings goals. I would be interested to hear your feedback.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try out [money.strands.com](https://money.strands.com). Pretty much all the functionality you'd expect from a money management app.

Answer (score 0):

[BudgetPulse](https://www.budgetpulse.com/) would be worth checking out!

> **Anyone in the world can use BudgetPulse** as this tool is designed with everyone in mind.
>
> Import your transaction data from your
> banking institutions, spreadsheets,
> and other budgeting tools and quickly
> customize your personal budget to suit
> your needs. Remember, your data is
> always secure and any private banking
> or personal information is kept
> strictly outside BudgetPulse, so your
> budget is not connected to any bank or
> credit institution. Your budget is at
> all times very personal, very private,
> and very safe.

Answer (score 0):

[PocketSmith](http://www.pocketsmith.com) would be also be worth checking out!

> Track spending, anywhere in the world.
>
> **We proudly support bank transaction
>   files from anywhere in the world.**
>   After all, we're an international
>   bunch ourselves. Even adding
>   transactions manually is a pleasure.

Other tools include:

- https://money.strands.com/, as
  previously suggested,
- https://www.pearbudget.com/,
- **and more, which you can find on [this article](http://www.thebudgetfashionista.com/archive/top-ten-online-money-management-tools/) and [this article](http://web.appstorm.net/roundups/finances-roundups/take-control-of-your-finances-with-the-web/).**

Answer (score 0):

[Yodlee.com](https://yodlee.com) are the guys who write the engine that almost all of these sites use (including Mint.com).

They have an own label site based on the engine at https://moneycenter.yodlee.com

It works very well, although it not as pretty as some of the others.

Answer (score 0):

France has [Linxo](http://www.linxo.com/), roughly the same features as Mint, I use it for my bank account (Société Générale), it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternatives you might find useful. They are available outside of the US.

- [Money2Manage](http://money2manage.com/)
- [Ronin](http://www.roninapp.com/)
- [Outright](http://outright.com/)
- [BudgetPulse](https://www.budgetpulse.com/)
- [Wave Accounting](http://waveaccounting.com/)

Comment: You should instead summarise here what the benefits of any of these are instead of dumping a batch of links to go read sales pitches instead of actual thoughts on what makes these any good.

Answer (score 0):

You may give [InEx Finance](https://www.inexfinance.com/) a try and see if it works for you. They position themselves as an international service by supporting most popular world currencies. Direct synchronization with bank accounts is not available. However, they offer many import options to upload bank statements (ofx, qif) and bulk cash transactions (csv).

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://getpocketbook.com - we are pretty new to the market but have the benefit of learning from a lot of failures. :)

Australians can sync with their banks but the app can be used internationally (you'll need to import your transaction from your bank's QIF file).

Comment: If you are the developer of/affiliated with getpocketbook, you should add a clear disclamer to your question.

Comment: Please see our [help/behavior].

Answer (score 0):

[Ahorro y punto](https://www.ahorroy.com) in Spain. And an API for developers: [API for banking](https://www.agregadorfinanciero.com).