# Mint alternatives for Canada

Tags: webapp-rec

Any suggestion for True North habitants?

Comment: Could you clarify what it should require because I could only assume Quebec will have a different system/policy in place as opposed to the rest of Canada

Comment: Possible dup http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/is-there-a-good-equivalent-to-mint-com-for-users-in-the-uk

Comment: @phwd: I live in Ontario, not aware of differences between QC and rest of Canada.

Comment: The question 1190 asks for Mint alternatives for UK. We Cannadians are  independent from the UK for couple of years now :-).

 Thanks for pointing it out, some of 1190 answers are wider than UK context.

Comment: So now I should go and ask one for the Netherlands and some other user for Germany and yet another for the Flemish part of Belgium (hi @fretje!)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://www.quickenonline.intuit.com/quickenweb/pages/iam/login_main.jsf and http://yodlee.com/ymc_home.shtml.

I found most of my into on the forum http://forums.redflagdeals.com/there-mint-com-substitute-canada-745910/.

It looks like there could be an issue because Canadian banks don't generally allow outside access to their accounts.  Mint was just purchased by Intiut so they probably haven't had time to get Canada integration since Mint was a smaller company.  I would try the Intuit one first as they are such a large and old org that if they don't support Canada then no one probably does.

Also, Wesabe.com would have been another option but they have closed down as of this month.