# Simple financial web app supporting cash flow

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for a simple financial web application in which I can track loans and cash flows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Indenero](http://indinero.com) -- it is made to easily manage your cashflow

Comment: I was looking for something like Indinero thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I can help!

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [Mint.com](http://www.mint.com)? They were recently acquired by Intuit, the makers of Quicken.

Comment: Mint.com is for US only isn't it?  The OP's listed location is outside the US.

Comment: Yes it is US-centric. You won't be able to use all of its features, sure,  but it's not useless for people outside US. I'm in Brazil and I use it :) At least until a more international friendly option appears.

Comment: Ok I'll try Mint.com since I have an American bank account to link with. Maybe the investments section could help. But I'm looking for something simpler.

Comment: It had some annoying UI bugs that prevented me from using it. Eg deciding that my line of credit was a checking account, and there is no way to change the type of account once it has decided on something.

Comment: Mint has good budget tools but does it actually have cash-flow specific tools?  I would like this feature too, but don't see anything beyond the normal budgeting stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Mint.com is definitely what I'd recommend for US users.  There are several related questions about Mint.com alternatives for those outside the US that may be of interest to you.

- [Mint alternatives for Canada](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2989/mint-alternatives-for-canada)
- [Is there a good equivalent to Mint.com for users in the UK?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/is-there-a-good-equivalent-to-mint-com-for-users-in-the-uk)
- [Mint alternatives for Israel](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2944/mint-alternatives-for-israel)

Answer (score 0):

[Pulse](http://pulseapp.com/) is free (with limited access), super easy to set up, and pretty flexible with how you can categorize income / expense items.

It doesn't try to hook into your financial data like inDinero, it just lets you throw recurring or non-recurring (dated) transactions into categorized lists and look at the cash flow.