# Which U.K. Banks work best with personal finance sites such as Mint.com & Xero

Tags: webapp-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a good equivalent to Mint.com for users outside the USA?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/is-there-a-good-equivalent-to-mint-com-for-users-outside-the-usa)

Which U.K. based banks work best with personal finance web-apps? (i.e. Allow direct import of data, rather that manual upload of csv's)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/is-there-a-good-equivalent-to-mint-com-for-users-outside-the-usa. So it might be worth having a look there for solutions :)

Comment: This is a valid question for the UK, I would also like to know this but particularly for small/ Freelance business.

Comment: @Scott localized financial questions are closed and merged to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/is-there-a-good-equivalent-to-mint-com-for-users-outside-the-usa There is enough discussion in there.

Comment: @Scott comment on the OP's question in http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/is-there-a-good-equivalent-to-mint-com-for-users-outside-the-usa and ask for additional requirements to be added, users with editing power will handle it from there.

Comment: Scott have a look at Freeagent - it's also mentioned in another question on this site.

Comment: The first half of the question is a duplicate of 1190, sorry. However, the second half is still valid I think, I've edited to make more of it.

Comment: Lol, closed before I changed it - never mind.

Answer (score -1):

The [Co-operative Bank](http://www.co-operativebank.co.uk/) personal accounts, rather uncooperatively, do **not** currently offer any export function at all.