# Personal Finance web applications for the UK market

Tags: webapp-rec

We are sadly without mint in the UK, however there are several other personal finance web applications out there.

I (and probably others) would like a comprehensive list of personal finance web applications for the UK market together with information about the features they support (i.e. importing bank statements, budgeting, bill payments etc.) and their general usability.

Hopefully this question could become the canonical destination on the web for users looking to select a online personal finance/money management application for the UK market.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good equivalent to Mint.com for users outside the USA?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/is-there-a-good-equivalent-to-mint-com-for-users-outside-the-usa)

Comment: I did see that question, but there are places other than the UK outside the US :) and I also thought that question wasn't general enough.

Comment: The other question is for everywhere outside the US, what isn't general about that?

Comment: The comment was in two parts:-

1.  My question is UK only, i.e. more specific.
2.  My question is not just about mint clones, i.e. more general.

Answer (score 0):

The main online personal finance aggregation services that I know of in the UK are yodlee.com and moneydashboard.net though the latter is a new service (in Beta) powered by the former (which is more established; I've been using it on and off for around two years).

Some more info/bit of background on the two services, and some discussion in the comments, here: http://eu.techcrunch.com/2010/05/12/money-dashboard-launches-its-bid-to-become-the-mint-for-the-uk/

and this article has some screenshots/talks a bit more about what the service offers: http://thenextweb.com/apps/2010/05/14/can-money-dashboard-become-the-uks-mint-com/

There are also a couple of others that need you to have an account with them: Egg Money Manager (though that one saves data on a specific computer rather than being entirely web based, and last time I used it it was Internet Explorer as it's ActiveX based - no dice for Mac users) and First Direct have an account aggregation service as well.

Been doing a bit of research into this and almost everything else I've seen is US-only unfortunately :) (Mint, Bundle etc)

Comment: +1 for Yodlee; Mint.com is actually powered by this, as are most of the others.  They also have rock solid support.

Answer (score 0):

[Love Money](http://www.lovemoney.com) is a UK-based finance package similar, I think, to Mint.com.

It supports most UK banks as far as I can tell. Will download your transactions and balances, let you categorise them, as well as do basic analysis and budgeting.

There was another one I'd tried earlier, but it's scraping service was a bit flaky and I think they've shut down now anyway. But Love Money seems pretty solid.

Comment: Have just added Money Dashboard... think I prefer it to Love Money at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [OnTrees](https://www.ontrees.com/).

> OnTrees is the free and simple way to see all your financial accounts in one place. You can check your balances, track your spending and set up budgets and alerts to manage your money more effectively.